# How to Call a Method in a Android Java Layer System Service from native code

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, native

I have an Android System Service [SS.java] with several methods. It has been added to Service Manager. I need to call one of the methods from a native service[N.cpp] or a native shared library.

From N.cpp, I am able to use defaultservicemanager()->getService("servicename") for native services.

But, is it possible to use a similar approach to call SS.Java?

Currently SS.java does not have any native component. It only has a corresponding ss.aidl.

Is a native interface needed? It is not possible to perform the implementation for the required method in native code because of dependencies.

It would be great if someone could give a detailed explanation of how to call a Java layer system service method from native code.

Comment: Take a look at JNI it goes native <-> Java (both ways)

Comment: @Hame: Thank you very much. I have tried Jni but since the jvm runs in a separate process, I am not able to access some data I am dependent on in the System Server process.